# Conditionally replace values using magrittr

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements, magrittr

Suppose I have a dataframe I would like to perform transformations on.
Normally it would look like:

```
a <- data.frame(c(NA, 0,1), c(34,NA,0), c(3,9,NA) )
b <- c('key1', 'key2', 'key3')
####replace NA values with 0
a[is.na(a)] <- 0
####replace 1 with 2
a[a==1] <- 2
####sum rows
a <- rowSums(a)
####bind b as key column for joining datasets in a later stage
c <- cbind(b, a)
```

Now my question is: how do I translate this to `magrittr`?

```
library(magrittr)
c %>% 
.[is.na] %>% 0 %>% .[.==1] %>% 2 %>%
rowSums %>% cbind(b, .)
```

gives me:

> Error in .[is.na(.)] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In is.na(.) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'builtin'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
    mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0))) %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(replace(., .==1, 2))) %>%
    rowSums(.) %>%
    data_frame(key = b, val = .)
#    key   val
#   <chr> <dbl>
#1  key1    37
#2  key2     9
#3  key3     2
```

Or without using the `dplyr` functions

```
 a %>% 
    is.na(.) %>%
    replace(a, ., 0) %>%
    replace(., .==1, 2) %>%
    rowSums() %>% 
    cbind(b, .)
```

Comment: Thank you, I do prefer a way without using another package. The replace function is what I was looking for.

Comment: related code for when `a` is not a pre-existing object but an intermediate step in the processing: `b %>% fun_make_a() %>% replace(., is.na(.), 0) %>% ...`

Answer (score 2):

A slightly quicker (in terms of typing, not sure if it's also faster in terms of computation) way than suggested by @akrun is using the `rec` function from the [sjmisc](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjmisc)-package:

```
library(sjmisc)
library(dplyr)

a <- data.frame(c(NA, 0,1), c(34,NA,0), c(3,9,NA) )
b <- c('key1', 'key2', 'key3')

a %>% 
  rec("NA=0;1=2;else=copy") %>% 
  rowSums(.) %>% 
  data_frame(key = b, val = .)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     key   val
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1  key1    37
# 2  key2     9
# 3  key3     2
```

Comment: Thank you, I will keep this one in mind for when I have a larger list of replacements to make.